# Is it possible to restrict attribute usage to only certain interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, css, custom-attributes

Let's say I have an interface `IAppModule`, implemented by a few classes. Is it at all possible to write a custom attribute that can only be applied to types that expose `IAppModule`? If so, how?

Comment: Instead of decorating those classes with attributes, try adding extra properties for that meta data to the interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's not possible.

You can, however, when using reflection to process your attributes, check if the decorated type is a class that implements the IAppModule interface.

`typeof(someType).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IAppModule))`

It doesn't stop users of your attribute from using it incorrectly (in any other class), but if you decide to go with this approach, I'd recommend providing very clear documentation describing how the attribute should be used and adding the layer of validation I mentioned above.

Comment: I think `someType is IAppModule` will do the same thing, but it looks more accurate.

Comment: In that case, `someType` could _be_ `IAppModule`. And ProfK only wants classes that implement that interface, not the interface itself.